# Java implementations of common data structures and algorithms

Tags: java

I'm looking for some standard implementations of a number of common data structures and algorithm, such as:

- Binary, AVL and red-black trees
- Tree visitors such as Euler tour
- (Weighted) graphs and DAGs
- Graph searches
- Travelling salesman algorithms such as Dijkstra's algorithm
- Minimum spanning trees/Krushal's algorithm

Etc etc etc.

I'd hoped there'd be an Apache common-XXX package, but alas not?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html mentions a Red-Black tree implementation.

Comment: Have you tried to Google what you need?

Comment: Java is an application oriented platform, not theoretically-oriented. You can find some of these implementations in the Collections Framework, but they are encapsulated and you only handle the functionality.

Comment: Graph libraries general enough to be usable in real life -- that aren't so general that nobody except theorists will use them -- are _really, really hard_ to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jgrapht.org/ provides the bottom 5, the trees are implemeted in core java.

Just a note : I couldnt remeber the  name and googled 'Java Graph Algortihms'. It was the first result. :)